# Asked in an interview today: Find the closest descendant of two elements in a binary tree

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Just wondering if I did this correctly at the interview today. The setup was

```
Node ClosestDescendent ( Node root, Node left, Node right ) 
{
   // ... 
}

class Node
{
    int val;
    Node left; 
    Node right;
}
```

e.g. for

```
     5
    / \ 
   4   6
  / \   \ 
 2   3   7
```

the `val` of the `ClosestDesendant` of the `left` and `right` nodes with `val`s `2` and `7` would be `5`, and the `val` of the `ClosestDesendant` of the `left` and `right` nodes with `val`s `2` and `3` would be `4`.

My implementation was

```
Node ClosestDescendent ( Node root, Node left, Node right ) 
{
    // assume left != right and both left and right are
    // nodes in the tree

    // figuring out which is the smaller and which is the bigger
    // simplifies logic later
    Node smaller, bigger; 
    if ( left.val < right.val ) { smaller = left; bigger = right; }
    else { smaller = right; bigger = left; }
    // traverse tree towards both left and right 
    // until the path diverges
    Node curnode = root; 
    while ( true ) 
    {
       if ( curnode.val < smaller.val && curnode.val < bigger.val ) 
       {
          curnode = curnode.right;
       }
       else if ( curnode.val > smaller.val && curnode.val > bigger.val )
       {
          codenode = cornode.left; 
       }
       else // curnode.val >= smaller.val && curnode.val <= biger.val
       {
           break;
       }
    }
    return curnode;
}
```

and I'm wondering

- Is this correct?
- Is this Skeet-certified?
- What is a better solution?

Comment: off-topic and your question aside but... are you, [Hillary Clinton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6048670/hillary-clinton), aware of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319809/what-is-the-policy-on-user-names-that-are-obvious-impersonators-of-actual-person) meta post?

Comment: without having verified whether or not the solution works, I'd be very concerned with the fact that you have about 50 % comments in your code, instead of trusting good variable names and well-factored methods to communicate for you. I'd also note that the code is "very imperative" and I'd personally prefer a more functional approach to a problem like this, but I guess that partly comes down to the fact that you're using an imperative language that doesn't have tail call optimization.

Comment: `codenode = cornode.left;` neither of these symbols are in scope, I assume you just misspelled `curnode`?

Comment: You're using unusual terminology here. Usually, when discussing trees, descendants are nodes that appear "below" or further away from the root. Nodes that are higher up or closer to the root would normally be termed ancestors.

Comment: Why do you assume a tree is a binary search tree? This problem is called Lowest Common Ancestor. Google it and find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pseudo-code:

```
// TODO: Null check, equality handling.
Node ClosestDescendent(Node root, Node left, Node right) {

  const int root_val = root->val;
  const int left_val = left->val;
  const int right_val = right->val;

  // left and right diverges two ways
  if ((left_val < root_val) && (right_val > root_val)) {
    return root;
  }

  // left and right both are to the left
  else if ((left_val < root_val) && (right_val < root_val)) {
    return ClosestDescendent(root->left, left, right);
  }

  // left and right both are to the right
  else ((left_val > root_val) && (right_val > root_val) {
    return ClosestDescendent(root->right, left, right);
  }    
}
```